# Parametrising the initial curve; what is the meaning of this geometrically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In the book of PDE by Kumar, at page 21, it is given that

[image]

However, I cannot understand how and why does the author parametrises the curves as 
$$x = s, \quad y = 0, \quad z = f(x),$$
i.e what does this mean geometrically.

Answer (score 2):

$x=s$, $y=0$ is just the $X$-axis. On that axis you have an initial datum $f(x)$. Thus your characteristics will be issued from each point of the form $(s,0,f(s))$ in the $XYZ$ space. Their union forms a surface $z=z(x,y)$  which is the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

The pde alone has infinite number of solutions.  We can visualize them as surfases,  but when we want it that goes through a specific curve like the one you have here,  there is only one solution surface.

Comment: and .... ? what is the point that you are trying to make ?

Comment: About the geometrical meaning of the curve...

Comment: Dmitri, I appreciate the effort, but I'm asking what is the geometrical meaning of such a parametrisation of characteristic and initial curve, and as far as I can understand, you are not talking something related to that.

Comment: In your curve,  you have $x=2$....

Comment: And in the book it is $x=s$...

Comment: it is just a typo, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This is a Cauchy problem,  so what is asked here is that solution of pde that takes on the curve of x, y plane the value f(x). I hope this helps.